# Register FreeBSD OPNsense Repo for `os-` plugins

Tags: freebsd, wireguard, opnsense, pkg

I have a community version of OPNsense runnung. I want to install the package `os-wireguard-go` on my machine. I found out that plugins will only be installable with a pro license. I also found this repo:

https://pkg.opnsense.org/FreeBSD:13:amd64/23.1/latest/All/

which seem to have all plungins available. I would like to add it to the

```
/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/OPNsense.conf
```

But I get a certificate error when doing so.

I would like to do something like:

```
fetch -o /usr/local/share/opnsense/pkg/fingerprints/pkg.opnsense.org.pub 
https://pkg.opnsense.org/pub/pkg.opnsense.org.pub
```

to obtain that fingerprint. I'm stuck here.

Could I also just `fetch` the https://pkg.opnsense.org/FreeBSD:13:amd64/23.1/latest/All/os-wireguard-go-1.13_5.pkg file and install it or is this something stupid to do?

The [docs](https://github.com/opnsense/update#opnsense-update) somehow say that the tooling uses the FreeBSD repo, which is disabled, but it is super confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new `.conf` called OPNsenseCore.conf and added the following lines and it worked:

```
OPNsenseCore: {
  fingerprints: "/usr/local/etc/pkg/fingerprints/OPNsense",
  url: "pkg+https://pkg.opnsense.org/${ABI}/23.1/latest",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  priority: 11,
  enabled: yes
}
```

the `pgk update` and you can see all plugins in the OPNsense WebUI.

Downside is that the original version is `23.4` and the repo only offers to `23.1`. Maybe someone can comment on this. I somehow saw that `opnsense-patch -c plugin` should somehow make it possible to update to the latest version. Also maybe someone could comment on that.